# How to pass two webhook id of different accounts in verify webhook API?

Tags: c#, paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

We have 2 different PayPal account and both account have same webhook address. We are using the "Verify webhook signature" API for verifying the webhooks.
So is there any possibility of passing 2 webhook id in the "Verify webhook signature" API ? For verifying the webhook is coming from either of this account.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. There might be a field in some webhooks that identifies which account it is from, but the usual solution is to use a different webhook address for each account.

Alternatively -- since verification is for your own information (for delivery purposes PayPal is only concerned that the address returns a 2xx success status) -- you could spam the verification endpoint with multiple (in this case up to two) verification attempts.